# Использование класса multiRouter.MultiRoute в Яндекс.Карты. Не могу разобраться, почему не отображается мультимаршрут по заданным точкам

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

```js
//Подключение Яндекс.Карты
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [45.186998, 38.998871],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: ['zoomControl'],
    });

    //Элемент 'Маршрут'
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: [
            'Новотитаровская',
            'Краснодар',
            'Динская'
        ],
        params: {
            routingMode: 'auto',
            viaIndexes: [1]
        }
    }, {
            boundsAutoApply: true
    });

    map.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
}
```

```css
body{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#map{
    min-height: 400px;
    min-width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style1.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Отслеживание перемещений транспорта</title>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="container">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <script src="scripts/script1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас полностью рабочий код кроме того, что вы не вписали полученный в [кабинете разработчика](https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/) api-ключ в соответствуюее место html-кода:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
```